# can a sum be distributed

Tags: summation, notation

For example:
$$\sum_i a_i(b_i - c_i)$$

Can it be rewritten as:

$$\sum_i a_i( \sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i)?$$

Thanks

Comment: No.  Ignoring convergence issues, you could rewrite it as $\left(\sum_i a_ib_i\right)-\left(\sum_i a_ic_i\right)$

Comment: No.  Where do the extra summation signs come from?  Try this when $i$ runs from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Reactions: [1] Your expression : $~~\sum_i a_i( \sum_i b_i - \sum_i c_i)~~$ is **overloading** the variable $i$, since you are using it for both an inner and outer summation.  A clearer expression would be $\sum_i a_i( \sum_j b_j - \sum_k c_k).~~$ [2] As suggested by saulspatz comment, the general approach to considering whether two summation expressions are equivalent is to **experiment** with small values.  For example,   in this case, you could let $i$ go from $1$ through $3$, make up small values for $(a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1, b_2, b_3, c_1, c_2, c_3)$ and manually check the two expressions.

Comment: Thanks everyone!